# Convert list item to string

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-itertools

I'm very new to Python and have relied on PHP as my go to server side scripting language of choice for years now. I'm using Python's [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to generate a list of combinations of way that a 6 digit number could be arranged.

```
import itertools
import threading

def test(full) :
   #print full
   codes = list(itertools.product([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], repeat=6))
   count = len(codes)

   for num in range(0, count):
       item = codes[num]
       print item
```

`item` is returned as what appears to look like an array. It's always a series of 6 number separated by commas and inside of parentheses.

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

How can I get the above value to be formatted as is below?

```
012345
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a nice way of doing that

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> ''.join(imap(str, item))
012345
```

Comment: Note that this creates a temporary list. The other solutions avoid that.

Comment: Edited it to no longer create a temporary list

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> series = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> ''.join(str(x) for x in series)
012345
```

The above will give you a string with all elements from `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` tuple. You can also convert it to `int` type (leading zero won't be preserved):

```
>>> int(''.join(str(x) for x in series))
12345
```

Answer (score 2):

What appears to look like an array is actually a `tuple`. But that is not crucial here, because you can use the `str.join` method to create a string out of the elements of any iterable (provided these elements are convertible to `str`):

```
>>> tpl = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> s = ''.join(str(i) for i in tpl)
>>> print s
012345
```

You can get more information on `str.join` by typing `help(str.join)` in the interactive interpreter.